# How fork() is executed in logical operator? How many times "Hi" is printed ? How?

Tags: ubuntu, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
(fork() && fork()) || (fork() && fork());
printf("Hi...\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's not just close it yet, it's fun, and this `fork` behaviour is POSIX strictly speaking, it's wise to know how it works in the UNIX world.

Comment: @Orion it looks like homework, feels like homework, smells like homework. That's acceptable in itself, but perhaps Ravi should do some of the legwork first. ("I've tried .... but ... so ...")

Comment: I agree, it looks suspicious.

Comment: @Orion for anyone who's not sure how this will play out, it's also trivial to compile and run this piece of code to determine the true answer to the number of times "Hi" is printed. _That_ is why I think it's laziness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that `fork` returns `0` for child and nonzero for parent. It gets quite convoluted, but you can sketch a tree of how the processes are forked.

`or` skips evaluation of the second argument if the first is `true`, because in that case, the result is known to be `true`. `and` skips the second argument, if the first is `false`, because in that case, the result is already known to be `false`. Every time the `fork` is called, two instances of the process exist with different results of the call. So, in some subprocesses, some forks will be called, but not the others.

A sketch (yellow means the fork-line is completed and the execution proceeds to the next line).
[image]